Dynamic Data Label Range for a Line Graph in vba
I have created a macro in VBA which creates a line chart.
The line chart uses dynamic range names for the X and Y axis which works fine.
However, I trying to use a dynamic range name for the data labels.
In VBA I have this line of code:
Graph_WS.Range("B330").Value2 = "=" & "'" & "Show score chart" & "'" & "!G181..G" & CStr(181 + Scoring_shots_to_end_of_qtr(4) * 2 - 1)

which should put ='Show Score Chart'!G181:G274 in cell B330.
Instead it is putting the @ sign in front, i.e., =@'Show Score Chart'!G181:G274
How can I fix this?

What happens if you use Graph_WS.Range("B330").Formula?

Use Graph_WS.Range("B330").Formula2 = ... . from the docs Formulas set using Range.Formula2 will always be evaluated as an array and may spill if more than 1 result is returned

Thanks for your suggestions. If I use .Formula it puts @ in front and if I use .Formula2 it produces a spill when I look in B330, believing it is an array. However, this is not what I want. It seems the only way I can get dynamic lables to work is to construct the formula in the actual cell B330 using: ="='"&C333&"'!G181:G"&TEXT(181+$B$176*2-1,0) and leaving calculations automatic on while I run the macro. Any thoughts ?

Graph_WS.Range("B330").Formula should bypass Excel's implicit intersection operator as this is a dynamic array formula
